# Node.js mysql selecting time variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, time

```
var query = "select * from ? where info = 1;"
var params = [table];  //table = 'light'
connection.query(query, params, function(err, rows) { //this rows returns 'undefined'
        console.log(rows);
        var sql = "UPDATE ? SET info = ?,off_time = '?',run_time = '?' WHERE info = '1'";
        var run_time = time_cal(formatted, rows);
        var params = [table, data, formatted, run_time];
            connection.query(sql, params, function(err, rows) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("update success!");
          }
        });
      });
```

mysql table at below

column | type

--------------------------------------+

info | tinyint(1) .......//1

--------------------------------------+

on_time | time   ........//10:00:00

--------------------------------------+

off_time | time  ........//11:00:00

--------------------------------------+

run_time | time  ........//01:00:00

--------------------------------------+

while selecting time variable by nodejs, rows have returned 'undefined'

how can i receive proper data?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is that table and column names cannot be replaced by parameters in parameters binding.